# Is "this" necessary in javascript apart from variable definition

Tags: javascript, this, scope, javascript-objects

My question is dead simple.

I just casually discovered that once you have defined a property with `this.` into an object, you don't need to prepend `this.` anymore when you want to call them.

So `this.` is really meant to be used ad definition time, like `var`?

I found it my self shortly after, i was referencing the window object with this. since i called my object without using new, so like it was a function.

One extra question, maybe for comments. Inside the main object, if i create a new object, and use `this` during the object definition, this `this` what will be referring to?

Comment: The short answer is 'no'. However, I don't really know enough about `this` to give you the full answer, so I shall leave that to someone else. Be prepared to learn about a whole lot of useful new functionality!

Comment: Can you please show an example? What you are describing is not right (unless this is the window object, and even then your description is only partly right).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unless the context of `this` is a **global** object, such as `window`. Take the following example:

```
function Foo(bar) {
    this.data = bar;
    console.log(this.data); // OK
    console.log(data); // ReferenceError
}
```

In this example, you'll get a `ReferenceError: data is not defined` on the first `console.log(data)`, *unless*, `data` is a global variable. To access the instance's public member, you *have* to use `this.data`.

#### References:

- [Understanding JavaScript’s `this` keyword](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/understanding-javascripts-this/)
- [The `this` keyword](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html)

Comment: Note that even if this is window you may still need to say this.someVariable if there is a local someVariable shadowing the global one.

Answer (score 2):

There are all sorts of circumstances where you MUST use `this` in order to reference the right data.

These two implementations do very different things:

```
Array.prototype.truncate(newLen) {
    // sets the length property on the current Array object
    this.length = newLen;
}

Array.prototype.truncate(newLen) {
    // sets a global variable named length
    length = newLen;
}

var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
arr.truncate(2);
```

You MUST use `this` in order to control what happens if you want to modify the current object.  Your assumption that you can leave it off and it will still modify the current object's properties is not correct.  If you leave it off, you are modifying global variables, not member properties.

Answer (score 1):

> So this. is really meant to be used ad definition time, like var?

No, the point of `this` is to be the current scope of execution.  You can (and will) run into weird errors if you don't use `this`.  For example, imagine you are an object with a property `val` and then on the prototype of that object you have

```
App.obj = function(){
   this.val = 'initial';
}

obj.prototype.myMethod = function(val) {
   // how would you assign argument val to object val?
}
```

also note that your reasoning breaks down with methods.

```
obj.prototype.meth2 = function(){
   myMethod();  // fails where this.myMethod() would work.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See http://jsfiddle.net/BRsqH/:

```
function f(){
    this.public='hello!';
    var hidden='TOP SECRET!';
}
var instance=new f();
alert('Public data: '+instance.public+ /* gives "hello!" */
    '\nHidden data: '+instance.hidden /* gives undefined */
);
```

Variables created with `var` are hidden and cannot be viewed nor modified outside the function which created them.

But variables created with `this` are public, so you can access them outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it.

I defined my object as `function My_Object(){...}` and then called it with `MyObject()`. This way the My_Object was treated as a function, not an object and therefore this == window.

So in the end I was attaching properties and methods to window instead of My_Object! That's way there were available without prepending `.this`.

The right way to initialize My_Object as an object is to call it like this `new My_Object`, isn't right?

Comment: You do now seem to understand.